# Counting duplicate value only once in excel or VBA , will auto calculate my total of room type when i adding new room

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

this is my Room record. i need to put formula or VBA code to count my type of room.

```
BedNum  RoomNum  RoomType         RoomType    totalcount
1001#1   1001     Studio           Studio         3
1001#2   1001     Studio           2br1cr         2
1001#3   1001     Studio           3br1cr         1
1002#1   1002     2br1cr
1002#2   1002     2br1cr
1003#1   1003     3br1cr
1003#2   1003     3br1cr
1004#1   1004     Studio
1004#2   1004     Studio
1005#1   1005     2br1cr
1005#2   1005     2br1cr
1006#1   1006     Studio
1006#2   1006     Studio
---------------------------------------------------------
above list is my Excel record , i wanna count in the rightside with formula or either VBA code ,
my RoomNumber will always increase and adding new room , what i want is total up the count of my roomtype.
```

Comment: Refer [this link](https://exceljet.net/formula/extract-unique-items-from-a-list) for extracting unique values in a list with formula in column C and in Column D you can use countif. If the list data starts from A2 then array (CSE) formula in C2 `=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$12,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($C$1:C1,$B$2:$B$12),0)),"")`

Comment: Just as a hint: You can do this in Access with a query.

Comment: What you describing is a pivot-table

Comment: @JvdV: Do you refer to my comment? Anyway, ho would you do the count with a pivot table?

Comment: @JvdV: Yes, you are right. It can be done with a pivot table as well. To be honest I've never used the option _Add data to the data model_

Comment: @Storax, not really, just to op =)

Answer (score 1):

As said in my hint you can use "database" technology to do this. I used the code below to achieve the following result

[image]

I started with the following layout

[image]

The sheet *shResult* is empty. I **renamed** the **codenames** accordingly!

[Reading on codename](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-worksheet/#Using_the_Code_Name_of_a_Worksheet)

[Reading on ADO](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-copy/#Using_ADO_and_SQL)

```
Sub ReadFromWorksheetADO()

    ' Goto Tools/Reference and
    ' add Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection

    conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" _
        & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"";"

    Dim query As String
    ' The name in the tab has to be shData
    query = "Select ID, Name From [shData$] GROUP BY Name,ID"

    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open query, conn

    ' Here I use the codename of the second sheet shResult!!
    With shResult
        .Cells.ClearContents
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
            .Cells(1, i + 1).Value = rs.Fields(i).Name
        Next i
        .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
    End With
    rs.Close

    ' Now I take the result of the first query and count
    query = "Select Name, count(ID) as CountOf From [shResult$] GROUP BY Name"
    rs.Open query, conn

    ' Here I use the codename of the first sheet shData
    With shData
        .Range("D2").CopyFromRecordset rs
    End With

End Sub
```

**PS1** I just saw that you changed your post but you just need to modify the code with the right fieldnames in order to get the following result

[image]

Modified code

```
Sub ReadFromWorksheetADO_B()

    ' Goto Tools/reference and
    ' add Microsoft ActiveX Dataa Objects
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection

    conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" _
        & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"";"

    Dim query As String
    ' The name in the tab has to be shData
    query = "Select RoomNum, RoomType From [shData$] GROUP BY Roomtype,RoomNum"

    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open query, conn

    ' Here I use the codename of the first sheet shResult!!
    With shResult
        .Cells.ClearContents
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
            .Cells(1, i + 1).Value = rs.Fields(i).Name
        Next i
        .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
    End With
    rs.Close

    ' Now I take the result of the first query and count
    query = "Select RoomType, count(RoomNum) as CountOf From [shResult$] GROUP BY RoomType"
    rs.Open query, conn

    ' Here I use the codename of the first sheet
    With shData
        .Range("E2").CopyFromRecordset rs
    End With

End Sub
```

**PS2**: One can combine the two queries above in one and one would save the extra sheet.

```
query = "Select RoomType, count(RoomNum) From (Select RoomNum, RoomType From [shData$] " & _
                "GROUP BY Roomtype,RoomNum) Group by RoomType"
```

And the final code looks like that then

```
Sub ReadFromWorksheetADO_C()

    ' Goto Tools/reference and
    ' add Microsoft ActiveX Dataa Objects
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection

    conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" _
        & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"";"

    Dim query As String
    ' The name in the tab has to be shData
    query = "Select RoomType, count(RoomNum) From (Select RoomNum, RoomType From [shData$] " & _
                        "GROUP BY Roomtype,RoomNum) Group by RoomType"

    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open query, conn

    ' Here I use the codename of the first sheet
    With shData
        .Range("E2").CopyFromRecordset rs
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks that i've try the code above , but the shDate show Run-time error, sHDate is not valid name.Make sure that it does no include invailid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long.

Comment: You need to modify the  codename of the sheet. The name is shData!

Comment: ok, Thanks you i just ammend and it's work , Thanks you alot for saving my time. Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

Well use countifs() and countif(), like this:

[image]

Edit:
And if you wish to produce a list automatically you can look at this, but getting the list to be sorted I leave to you:
[image]

Comment: unable to create the unique list, because my data id will increase and update frequently

Comment: @Hakunamatata then you should have written a better question. Take the process and match it to your data.

Comment: @Hakunamatata see edit for a way you can start  to create your automatic unique list...