# Excel VBA - creating a record table

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a script to make a table to summarise which customer has spend the most money in my store. I have a database with unique names in column A, values in column H and other different data.

The core of the script should work like this:

1. Search for unique name
2. Sum all the cells from "KWOTA" column (H column)
3. Paste name and sum of range into the other sheet.

The problem is, I don't know which way should I take. I planned to search row by row for the names through Do Until...Loop method and - if the name is repeating - add corresponding value to a range. The problem is, it will be necessary to create multiple ranges, one for each name (I don't know how many unique names I have in database) and manipulate with them. I really wish to avoid 'Add to range" method.

Is there a possibility to do it in one script, without help of another worksheet to list all the unique names first?

Comment: Why a script? sumifs() can do that for each name then find the max and use index() with match() to get the relevant name

Comment: yes, but I must retreive unique name list first, am I wrong?

Comment: So have a look at this and apply / edit it to what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62118998/4961700

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using the `Find` and `FindNext` methods to locate the unique names and add the value from the H column until all the unique names have been found.

Hope I interpreted your question correctly.

Example format:

```
Sub Find()

    Dim longSum As Long
    Dim SearchRange As Range
    Dim CellWithUniqueName As Range
    Dim FirstUniqueCell As String

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

    Set SearchRange = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))
    Set CellWithUniqueName = SearchRange.Find(What:="uniquename")

    FirstUniqueCell = CellWithUniqueName.Address


    Do
        Set CellWithUniqueName = SearchRange.FindNext(CellWithUniqueName)
        longSum = longSum + CellWithUniqueName.Offset(0, 7).Value

    Loop While CellWithUniqueName.Address <> FirstUniqueCell

'whatever else for pasting etc


End Sub
```

Comment: @LGusti if it works could you accept the answer, thanks!